# Partial assignment to signal of record type when setting initial value

Tags: vhdl, fpga, asic

Is it possible to do partial assignment to a record type on initialization?
Something like:

```
type t_foo is record
    a : integer;
    b : std_logic;
end record;

signal bar : t_foo := (b => '0');
```

In case of a normal signal assignment I could do:

```
bar.b <= '1';
```

This is however not possible when initializing a signal or constant. To me it looks like all record members must be assigned when setting the initial value or none at all.
There is probably a workaround possible using functions, but is there a simpler/better/native way?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.4.2.3 Signal declarations paragraph 5 (in part) "The default expression defines a *default value* associated with the signal or, for a composite signal, with each scalar subelement thereof." For a composite type (including a record) each subelement is represented.  5. Types, 5.1 General paragraph 10 "The term *subelement* is used in this standard in place of the term *element* to indicate either an element, or an element of another element or subelement. Where other subelements are excluded, the term *element* is used instead."

Comment: 8.3 Selected names para 1 "A selected name is used to denote a named entity whose declaration appears either within the declaration of another named entity or within a design library." Your assignment to `bar.b` is only to element `b`. The point here is that `bar` is the object not `bar.b`. The declaration of `bar` is a *single-object declaration* (6.4.2 Object declarations, 6.4.2.1 General paragraph 3).

Comment: Thank you @user1155120  for giving the LRM standpoint on this. However, I can imagine there are other ways to achieve what the question is asking, outside the scope of the LRM.

Answer (score -1):

Since it is possible to have default values for function parameters, one possible workaround to achieve a "partial initialization" can be the use of a init function:

```
type t_foo is record
    a : integer;
    b : std_logic;
end record;

function init_t_foo(a : integer := 83423; b : std_logic := 'Z') return t_foo is
    variable ifoo : t_foo;
begin
    ifoo.a := a;
    ifoo.b := b;
    return ifoo;
end function init_t_foo;

constant bar : t_foo := init_t_foo(b => '1');
```

When calling the function only those parameters which should have non-default values are supplied, the other parameters will remain unchanged.

EDIT: fixed variable assignment.

Comment: Not quite complete. 9.3.4 Function calls para 3 "For each formal parameter of a function, a function call shall specify exactly one corresponding actual parameter. This actual parameter is specified either explicitly, by an association element (other than the actual part open) in the association list, or in the absence of such an association element, by a default expression (see 6.5.2)." 6.5.2 Interface object declarations para 7 "If an interface declaration contains a “:=” symbol followed by an expression, the expression is said to be the *default expression* of the interface object. ..."

Comment: You could also note ifoo is class variable (should use variable assignment statements). Without the default expression the `init_t_foo` function call can't be matched with the function declaration.

Comment: You still don't provide a *default expression* for the parameter `a` declaration in the `init_t_foo` subprogram declaration.  See the BNF in 6.5.2 Interface object declarations. If you construct a [mcve] out of your snippets it would not successfully analyze (compile) without the default expression. While [adding the default expression allows analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1fRR.jpg).

Comment: Your confusion may stem from the difference between an object declared by a variable declaration and an interface object declaration (6.5.2). For the former (6.4.2.4 Variable declarations) "If the variable declaration includes the assignment symbol followed by an expression, the expression specifies an initial value for the declared variable; the type of the expression shall be that of the variable. Such an expression is said to be an *initial value expression*." and "In the absence of an initial value expression, a default initial value applies." Doesn't apply without an actual.

Comment: 6.5.2 paragraph 9 "An interface object provides a channel of communication between the environment and a particular portion of a description. The value of an interface object may be determined by the value of an associated object or expression in the environment; similarly, the value of an object in the environment may be determined by the value of an associated interface object. The manner in which such associations are made is described in 6.5.7." The associated interface object has no value without the default expression.

Comment: 6.5.7.1 para 17 (in part) "If an interface element in an interface list includes a default expression ... for a formal variable or constant parameter of mode in ... then any corresponding association list need not include an association element for that interface element. For ... a formal variable or constant parameter, if the association element is not included in the association list, or if the actual is **open**, then the value of the default expression is used as the actual expression ... in an implicit association element for that interface element." It's in an association.